# WAMP.ws : How to manage security and privacy?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, privacy, autobahn

I'm using WAMP.ws specifications to design public/private user chatrooms on my website.

My problem comes when I try to keep a list of all connected users.
What I could do :

1. All users subscribe to "/contacts/connections" topic.
2. When an user connects he publishes a "hello" message with a "user_id" argument, telling other users that he is connected.

--> But how can I trust users ? Any user could send an "Hello" message with a random "user_id" argument.

To me, the server have to do some checks before broadcasting the message. But is it in accordance with WAMP.js specifications ? I've read that a published message is always broadcasted by server.

Another solution could be using an RPC call to connect an user. Actually, I did that for authenticating users. But can the server broadcast an Event to topic "/contacts/connections" by itself ? (after a RPC call, not after "Publish" message)
I've read that Event are only the direct result of a "Publish" from client.
Moreover, this would not prevent regular users to send event trought "/contacts/connections" topic, which will be broadcasted by the server.

I feel that my two solutions (checking published messages before broadcasting, or broadcast of an event by server after an RPC call) both break WAMP.js specifications.
Am I wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WAMP differentiates between

1. Authentication
2. Authorization
3. Validation

**Authentication** establishes the identity of a WAMP client at a WAMP router.

When using [Autobahn|Python](http://autobahn.ws/python/) to roll your own WAMP router, [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/authentication) are multiple examples showing how to implement different authentication mechanisms.

When using [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/) (an integrated, production ready WAMP router), authentication mechanisms come built in ([here](http://crossbar.io/docs/Authentication/)).

---

**Authorization** determines if a given WAMP client is allowed to perform a WAMP action (like publish or call) on a given URI.

When using [Autobahn|Python](http://autobahn.ws/python/) to roll your own WAMP router, [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/authorization) is an example showing how to implement custom authorization.

Crossbar.io has a builtin static authorization scheme as well as allows to register custom WAMP procedures for authorization ([here](http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization/)).

---

Finally, there is **Validation**, which checks the application level payload of events or calls.

[Here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/validation) is an example for Autobahn|Python. Crossbar.io will soon allow to register custom WAMP procedures for validation.

---

Comment: The first link `Custom Publish & Subscribe Handler` is broken. Could you point it to the proper location?

Comment: @hazzey I've revised the whole answer for WAMP2. The old answer was for WAMP1, which is deprecated anyway.

Comment: You really have to start linking your Github links to a commit rather than `master`, I've come across many google results of you linking to 404's.